# React modal using reactstrap issue

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, reactstrap

I created a modal using reactstrap and while opening the modal it blurs the background and coming to the front, but after creating build and running using express it does not blur the background and does not comes forward. Why is the react and how can I resolve it. I tried looking for different solutions but I was unable to find anything corresponding to it.

Code for reference : [Modal Page](https://codesandbox.io/s/hooks-modal-forked-ly093)

Let me know if anyone needs any further information.

Answer (score 0):

***you can use material-UI Modal. ***